# datatype.date annotation not showing calendar in firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model with a date field and I've annotated it with:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
```

after doing this when I go into the view and click on the input box, a calendar shows up underneath, where I can pick a date. This works in Chrome but in firefox the calendar doesn't show up, is this a common problem with a fix?

Comment: Not all browsers support the new HTML5 `input` types equally.

Comment: `<input type="date" ..>` is still not supported in FireFox. [See comparison here](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/chrome-39/firefox-34/opera-24.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you use EditorFor helper to generate HTML for a model. As John wrote - it depends on browser so it's not reliable. However you can use editor templates to customize the HTML generated for your models. Personally I think the best solution will be jQuery date picker.